# Users and User Controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

In my User controller, I have the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
.....
def system_users
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # system_users.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end

def edit_system_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # edit_system_user.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
```

In my views/users/system_users.html.erb, I have:

```
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">
        <td><%= link_to user["first"], edit_system_user_path(user["id"]) %></td>
        <td><%= user["last"] %></td>
        <td><%= user["email"] %></td>
    <% end %>
```

In my routes, I have:

```
       edit_system_user        /edit_system_user(.:format)         user#edit_system_user
```

But, when I click on the link in the actual view generated by views/users/system_users.html.erb, I get the following error message:

```
uninitialized constant UserController
```

My user controller is pluralized, so where is the UserController coming from? Shouldn't it be going to the UsersController?

Comment: Is the name of your file `users_controller.rb`?

Comment: your route should have `edit_system_user        /edit_system_user(.:format)         users#edit_system_user` instead of `user#edit_system_user`. What do you have in your config/routes.rb?

Comment: In my routes.rb, I had mistakingly used user instead of users. This solved the issue. If you answer this, I'll approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes file is incorrect. It should say "**users**#edit_system_user" not "**user**#edit_system_user"